# Change Xmlspy editor background color

Tags: background, editor, xmlspy, altova

I was wondering if anyone of you knows if it is possible to change Altova's XMLSPY editor background color.

I've googled but I didn't find anything about this topic, and I'm sadly assuming there's no hope to change the bg color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools -> Options

Go to the text fonts tab and check "use the same for all". Press the icon above and set the background to a darker color.

Of course the usual text is black so make sure to change that to a lighter color. Just look at the preview and click on any text you can't see. Click on the icon with a little 'a' and set the text to a lighter color.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question - it's not about font color nor font background - but how to change editor background which is for me (version 2015 sp1) blueish gradient.

I have gone thru the "options" and "customize" menu and there is nothing in that regard.

Their sister product UModel can do that by finding "Styles" docking window and looking for "Diag. Background Color" and setting it to e.g. "White" instead "gradient".

Unfortunately I don't see equivalent feature in XML Spy.

Also, I quickly looked at the exe file where I saw plenty of RGB values stored, I don't know does that mean the value is hard coded or it's just complicated to find background image settings.